# I'm trying to center icons on my footer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a list of icons in my footer. I have tried multiple things but for some reason it isn't turning out how I want.

My CSS:

```
.social-icons {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.social-icons ul {
  align-items: center;
}

.social-icons li {
  display: inline;
}

.social-icons li img {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.social-icons li img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
        <ul class="social-icons">
          <li><img src="images/discordicon.png" alt="Discord Icon"></li>
          <li><img src="images/skypeicon.png" alt="Skype Icon"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: remove `ul` from `.social-icons ul`

Comment: @MichaelCoker That didn't do anything

Comment: align: center is outdated, use text:align: center;

Comment: @JordanFleetwood oh, use `text-align: center`, not `align-items: center`. The `align-items` property is for `flex` layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text-align: center;` to the footer itself, apple `display: inline-block` to the `ul` (to reduce its width to the actual content and thereby make the centering possible) and also `padding: 0;` to avoid the left default padding/offset:

```css
.footer {
  text-align: center;
}
.social-icons {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

.social-icons li {
  display: inline;
}

.social-icons li img {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.social-icons li img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <ul class="social-icons">
    <li><img src="images/discordicon.png" alt="Discord Icon"></li>
    <li><img src="images/skypeicon.png" alt="Skype Icon"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw the image you linked in your comment below the other answer: Could be the default left padding (see my answer above)

Comment: @Johnannes Actually I have another problem now. I tried adding another element to my footer and it shifted everything around weirdly? https://i.gyazo.com/ccdad9e3c8cb7d5259b074e60fe657c5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can center elements by various of methods. In your case, adding `text-align: center;` to `.social-icons` selector will be the fastest way.

here is the code:

```css
div.footer {
    width: 100%;
}

.social-icons {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.social-icons li {
    display: inline;
}

.social-icons li img {
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.social-icons li img:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
        <ul class="social-icons">
            <li><img src="images/discordicon.png" alt="Discord Icon"></li>
            <li><img src="images/skypeicon.png" alt="Skype Icon"></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a full guide of that : [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! For some reason, my centering seems a little off? https://i.gyazo.com/cc863d58820e84887710d5ac46596cc1.jpg

Comment: @JordanFleetwood seems ok on the pic, only the footer bar is about 2px or 3px margin from the bottom. You can share the full source code and tell us what is the issue you're experiencing and we will gladly help.

Comment: I think I've fixed that problem. However, how do I make it so I don't have to change a bunch of stuff every time I want to add something new to the footer?

Comment: @JordanFleetwood if you meant the 2px margin that I've mentioned, then you need to make your footer position fixed or absolute, and give it bottom: 0; with margin: 0; this should do the trick. other things you need to consider the elements need to be organized probably. So, whenever you add or change something everything should be in its place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the icons to the center of the screen, then there are two ways possible. Both work flawlessly. The first method is using CSS and the second one directly by typing a HTML tag into My HTML.

**Method 1 (using CSS)**

```css
.footer {
  text-align: center;
}
.social-icons {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

.social-icons li {
  display: inline;
}

.social-icons li img {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.social-icons li img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
        <ul class="social-icons">
          <li><img src="images/discordicon.png" alt="Discord Icon"></li>
          <li><img src="images/skypeicon.png" alt="Skype Icon"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

The above is the same code of the accepted answer. This one really works and is made by making a modification to the *My CSS* by adding a line to align the items in the footer to the center.

**Method 2(Using Center Tag)**
I'm surprised to see that no one has mentioned about the HTML **`<center>`** tag. Yes, you can center the items just by adding this tag to *My HTML*.

```css
.social-icons {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.social-icons ul {
  align-items: center;
}

.social-icons li {
  display: inline;
}

.social-icons li img {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.social-icons li img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <center>
        <ul class="social-icons">
          <li><img src="images/discordicon.png" alt="Discord Icon"></li>
          <li><img src="images/skypeicon.png" alt="Skype Icon"></li>
        </ul>
  </center>       
</div>
```

It is that easy. **But remember one thing, the center tag is not supported in HTML5. In this case, you have to use CSS.**
Hope this helps...
To know more about center tag : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp